# android how play video automatically by intent without press start

Tags: java, android, android-intent, video

I want to play video from app by intent.
I set specific component (vlc). it opened by this by I need press play.
Is there a way to start the video automatically??

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://media/external/video/media/249"), "video/mp4");
    intent.setPackage("org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: That is up to the implementers of the app.

Comment: You know apps that do this automatically?

Comment: Again, that will be up to the implementers of those apps. They could change their behavior over time. There is no requirement that a third-party video player automatically start up playback in response to an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. Some may today but will not do it tomorrow. Moreover, you have no way to force the user to install VLC or any other particular video player. Please allow the user to choose the video player that they want and do not worry about immediate playback, or write your own video player as part of your own app.

Comment: I understand what you mean.

I just want example for app that do it.
Even it "Some may today but will not do it tomorrow.."

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instruction VLC published on its official wiki-page and the video starts playing automatically on my device, without pressing the Play button.

https://wiki.videolan.org/Android_Player_Intents/